# Are we done here?

Tags: phrase-requests

Today I was getting help from someone behind a counter and when I had handed in my form and shown my ID, I wasn't sure if I needed to do anything else, or if I was free to go. Usually in that situation I say something like "いいですか？" and the employee quickly lets me know if I'm still needed.

But this time the employee asked me "いいですか？" before I had the chance. I took that to mean that we were finished and he wanted to know if I needed anything else, which was fine, except that I wasn't sure how to respond. I wanted to say that if the form was in order, then I didn't need anything else. I guess I'm looking for a way to politely ask "Are we done?" in Japanese.

Comment: It is hard for me to imagine the situation where someone hands the form and shows the ID to an employee behind a counter and the employee asks “いいですか.”

Comment: Well, he helped me finish filling out the form and we had talked about which copy goes to whom, etc, and then he picked up his papers and I picked up my papers and there was a pause. This is the point at which I wanted to ask him "いいですか。", but he said it instead. (He may have said something else that I didn't notice, but I don't think so.) I interpreted it as something like "Will there be anything else?"

Answer (score 7):

A rather straightforward sentence might work:

> 他に何かありますか。

Literally asking if there's anything else.

Answer (score 3):

I think a simple 「大丈夫です。」would fit nicely in this situation.

Comment: That's not really a question though...